# Vectorizing a MATLAB loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to do my best and not use loops in Matlab, but I find it very hard sometimes .

For example I wrote this code :

```
vector = zeros(p,1);

diagDominantFlag = 1;
for row = 1:p
    for col = 1:q
        if(row ~= col)
            vector(row) = vector(row) + A(row,col);
        end
    end
    if(A(row,row) <= vector(row))
        diagDominantFlag = 0;
        break;
    end
end
```

Is it possible to vectorize that double `for` loop?

Thanks

Comment: I've edited the question, since "breaking" a loop means something totally different to "vectorizing" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your direct question, but, here's a loopless test for diagonal dominance (since you seem interested in that):

```
all(diag(A) >= (sum(abs(A),2)-abs(diag(A)) )
```

or for strict diagonal dominance:

```
all(diag(A) > (sum(abs(A),2)-abs(diag(A)) )
```

Also, in your above code, make sure you do `abs()` on the off-diagonal values.

Comment: +1 for the `abs()` observation. Nevertheless, I'll stick to the OP's original code in my answer...

Comment: @EitanT I originally thought the same, but I've never seen a definition of diagonal dominance that didn't want the `abs()`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the inner loop with

```
vector(row) = sum(A(row, :)) - A(row, row);
```

and in fact you can replace the whole thing by

```
vector = sum(A, 2) - diag(A);
```

To add the check you have in the outer loop, you can then do something like

```
f = find(diag(A) <= vector);
if length(f) > 0
    diagDominantFlag = 0;
    vector(f(1):end) = 0;
end
```

Comment: +1 for the calculation of `vector`. The inner loop can be replaced by a vectorized comparsion, though...

Comment: Which inner loop? In the OPs question? That loop fills in the vector variable, so I don't see how a comparison would replace that .. can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant to say that the whole ordeal can be replaced by one logical vectorized comparison. Note that the flag retains the value of 1 only if each element in the diagonal is greater or equal to the corresponding element in `vector`. It's called diagonal dominance.

Comment: @Ansari: Can I use `abs` somewhere here ? since I need to take the absolute value and the rest of the elements of each line , and compare the sum of the absolute value of them with `a_ii` . Thanks .

Comment: vector(row) = sum(abs(A(row, :))) - abs(A(row, row));

Comment: Yes if diagonal dominance is what you're after, then replace any occurence of `A` with `abs(A)`. You can just use the second line (sum(A, 2) - diag(A)) to replace the whole thing, unless you only want to vectorize the inner loop for some reason. @EitanT - noted!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ansari's answer, the `diagDominantFlag` can be calculated by:

```
diagDominantFlag = all(diag(A) >= (sum(A, 2) - diag(A)));
```

Thus replacing your double `for` loop with a one-liner.

Comment: Okay,this is really nice.I'll try to remove all the loops from my code.